# React App on Google Cloud Storage- Js and Css are not getting loaded- giving 404

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I created react app with following command:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Then executed the command, to create build:

```
npm run build
```

Then uploaded the build folder output to gcp storage.

And when I am trying to access the index.html file via Link URL. In Console I am getting 404 for Css and Js file referenced in index.html

When I updated the index.html with correct url link of js and css, then it is working fine.
Is it necessary to change the js and css link reference to gcp storage url link? Can't that work with relative paths?

Comment: When you ran `npm run build` did you notice the part where it said which path it assumes for the installation and how to change it?

Comment: All your stored filed should be public. Is it public?

Comment: As such no information when I executed npm run build. Output- The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root. You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
@Lonewolf All the files are public.

Comment: Uh... that *is* the information. Put the correct url to the homepage field in your package.json.

Comment: I have tried adding the homepage as "homepage": "https://storage.cloud.google.com/bucketname" and "homepage": "." , It's giving the same error.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on how you uploaded your files to Cloud Storage.

You can do `gsutil rsync -R local-dir gs://www.example.com` to recursively copy a directory tree to Cloud Storage. [Which what the -R option is used for](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#uploading_your_sites_files)

Comment: This is to copy the files recursively. It will not update the js and css reference links.